# How to perform this complex calculation using SQL?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, database

Sorry for the vague title, but I can't figure out a clearer one to describe my situation.

I have a MySQL table storing the referencing relationships between articles. The table structure is given below:

Table name: **PaperReferences**

| PaperID | ReferencedPaperID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 4 |
| 5 | 1 |
| 5 | 4 |
| 6 | 1 |
| 7 | 1 |

I want to calculate an indicator for each paper, defined as the number of papers that cite it but not its references. For example, this indicator for `paper 1` is 2 since it has 3 citations (5, 6, 7) but only 2 do not cite its references (6, 7). In other words, `paper 5` is not counted because it also cites `paper 4`, which is one of the references of `paper 1`.

I am currently doing it with Python and iterations. However, it is too slow and I wonder if I can get the results using a single SQL query.

The most tricky part for me is to filter out invalid citing papers that also cite `paper 1`'s references.

Comment: could you show your actual table and column names?  and are you trying to get this indicator for a single paper id or for all papers with citations or all papers even if they have no citations?

Comment: @ysth I have modified the column names to actual ones, and I am trying to get this indicator for all papers (zero when they have no citations).

Comment: If you want papers with no cites, there'll need to be a table for papers too?

Comment: DB Fiddle would be great for your question. Prepare data and describe desired results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First figure out what is disallowed, then Join it to your citation list.

Cycles that are disallowed:

```
Select DISTINCT X.PaperID as Citer, Y.PaperID as disallowed 
From PaperReferences X Inner Join PaperReferences Y
    On X.ReferencedPaperID=Y.ReferencedPaperID
Where X.PaperID<>Y.PaperID
```

Now left join the table to this disallowed set, filter out the matches, and count your total:

```
Select ReferencedPaperID as paper, Count(*) as citations
From PaperReferences A Left Outer Join (
    Select DISTINCT X.PaperID as Citer, Y.PaperID as disallowed 
    From PaperReferences X Inner Join PaperReferences Y
        On X.ReferencedPaperID=Y.ReferencedPaperID
    Where X.PaperID<>Y.PaperID
    ) Z on A.PaperID=Z.Citer And A.ReferencedPaperID=Z.Disallowed
Where Z.disallowed Is Null
Group By ReferencedPaperID
```

Comment: NB: The DISTINCT is necessary  because there *could be* multiple paths to exclude 5, though this example does not show it.  Add a (5, 3) entry to this table and you will have created 2 ways to exclude 5,  the existing 1,4,5,1 cycle and a 1,3,5,1 cycle.

Comment: I gradually understand the `disallowed` table. In your first code block, you find all papers that share at least one reference of the given paper but these papers need not cite the given paper. Then you exclude those `bibliographic coupling` papers (terms to describe this type of papers) from the citations of a given paper. However, I do have an additional question. Is there a performance problem since the disallowed papers may not cite the given paper, but they are still considered as disallowed (which is unnecessary)?

Comment: For example, if I add a row (8, 4) to the table, then 8 is disallowed for 1 and 5 because it cites 4. However, 8 does not cite 1 or 5 so it would be unnecessary to be considered?

Comment: To figure out whether any of these cites anything else, you would need to join one **more** time, and THAT would be a performance penalty.  In general, the fewer tables joined, the better the performance.

Comment: If you want to ensure optimal performance make sure you have an index on ReferencedPaperID.

Comment: Added Where clause to filter out unnecessary 'join to self' records in disallowed set results.  Does not change results but cuts down on temp data set size.

Answer (score 1):

I'm curious to know why your Python is so slow.  Doesn't this solve the problem pretty quickly?

```
data = (
(1, 2),
(1, 3),
(1, 4),
(5, 1),
(5, 4),
(6, 1),
(7, 1)
)

import collections
cite = collections.defaultdict(set)
cited = collections.defaultdict(set)

for row in data:
    cite[row[0]].add(row[1])
    cited[row[1]].add(row[0])

# We remove 5 from cited[1] because cite[1] and cite[5] overlap.

for k,v in cited.items():
    toremove = set()
    for c in v:
        if cite[k] & cite[c]:
            print(f"removing {c} from {k}")
            toremove.add( c )
    v -= toremove

print(cite)
print(cited)

for k,v in cited.items():
    print( f"{k} has {len(v)} sole citations" )
```

Comment: Because the table is too large to store in memory, so I have to query the references and citations for each paper every time. I think it significantly harms the performance.

Comment: @TomLeung Actually I'm more surprised why not generator expressions instead of `for`s. With generator expressions it will not use more RAM, performance most probably will be the same or better

Comment: @AlexYu Thanks for the insight! As all the data is stored in the database, my Python program calculates the indicator for papers one by one and performs more than one SQL query to find references and citations. I think using a SQL query that yields all the results at once may be much faster so I ask this question.

Comment: Most probably perfoming calculation in SQL is the right way but not because performance reasons. I suppose it must be possible to be faster in python. Large amounts of data could be dealt with something like `pytables`. It's to share results between multiple consumers database would be better

Comment: How many records are there?  My code only makes one sequential pass over the rows, so the cursor can read stuff a bit at a time.  If you can't store those two dictionaries in memory, then I don't know how you will solve the problem.

Comment: There are about 1.8 billion rows in my reference table and my server has only 300GB of memory. I may add more memory to the server as it seems the most straightforward way to allow me to load those two dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
select ReferencedPaperID, count(*) as indicator
from PaperReferences p
left join (
  select b.PaperID
  from PaperReferences a
  join PaperReferences b on b.PaperId = a.PaperId
  join PaperReferences c on c.ReferencedPaperID = b.ReferencedPaperID
  where a.ReferencedPaperID = c.PaperId
) f on f.PaperId = p.PaperId
where f.PaperId is null
group by ReferencedPaperID
```

Result:

```
 ReferencedPaperID  indicator 
 ------------------ --------- 
 2                  1         
 3                  1         
 4                  1         
 1                  2
```

See running example at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cmsyHXUpyk14UsT6EFDf2h/0).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! However, I think @Chris Maurer 's answer may be more suitable as the indicator for paper 4 should be 2, not 1.

Comment: In this example, 4 should be counted twice.  It is cited by both 1 & 5 and it cites nothing itself.  That inner query just returns 5, so 5 is excluded in all contexts.  In the (1, 5) context it is correct, but in the (4, 5) context it needs to be counted.